# Epoch time of CMTime

Tags: avfoundation, cmtime

Apple's AVFoundation documentation has the following for CMTime:

"The epoch number of a CMTime is usually set to 0, but you can use it to distinguish unrelated timelines. For example, the epoch could be incremented each cycle through a presentation loop, to differentiate between time N in loop 0 from time N in loop 1."

I don't grock the example.  Can anyone elaborate?